# Schema <[object Object]> already exists with different definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Getting `Schema <[object Object]> already exists with different definition` error while trying to refer 2 schemas in one.

Please correct me if am doing something wrong:

> *Coupons Schema* in coupons.js

```js
const COUPONS_SCHEMA = {
  "id": "/Coupons",
  "items": {
    "id": "/items",
    "properties": {
      "Description": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Ean": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ExpiryDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "StartDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Type": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "VoucherValue": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "type": "object"
  },
  "type": "array"
};

export default COUPONS_SCHEMA;
```

> *Rewards Schema* in rewards.js

```js
const REWARDS_SCHEMA = {
    "id": "/Rewards",
    "items": {
        "id": "/items",
        "properties": {
            "PromotionId": {

                "type": "string"
            },
            "Reward Amount": {

                "type": "string"
            },
            "RewardType": {

                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    },
    "type": "array"
};

export default REWARDS_SCHEMA;
```

Am referencing above defined schemas in **Discounts Schema**

```js
import { Validator } from 'jsonschema';
import Coupons from './coupons';
import Rewards from './rewards';
let validator = new Validator();


const DISCOUNTS_SCHEMA = {
  "id": "/Discounts",
  "properties": {
    "Coupons": {
    "$ref": "/Coupons"
    },
    "PromotionalClubCardPoints": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Rewards": {
      "$ref": "/Rewards"
    },
    "StaffDiscount": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "StandardClubCardPoints": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalClubCardPoints": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalCoupons": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalGiftCards": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalGreenClubCardPoints": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalSavings": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TotalVouchers": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
};

validator.addSchema(Coupons,'/Discounts');
validator.addSchema(Rewards,'/Discounts');


export default DISCOUNTS_SCHEMA;
```

```js
and getting the below error 

 throw new Error('Schema <'+schema+'> already exists with different definition');
        ^

Error: Schema <[object Object]> already exists with different definition
    at Validator.addSubSchema (/Users/repo/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:72:15)
    at Validator.addSubSchemaArray (/Users/repo/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:99:10)
    at Validator.addSubSchema (/Users/repo/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:80:8)
    at Validator.addSchema (/Users/repo/node_modules/jsonschema/lib/validator.js:48:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/repo/src/schema/discounts.js:47:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (/Users/repo/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/repo/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Please correct me if am doing something wrong in defining schemas.

Comment: Can we please see the Validator class/function ?

Comment: Validator function is imported from 'jsonschema' npm package

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you use the `id` "/items" in both coupons.js and rewards.js.  `id`s need to be universally unique.  That is why they are supposed to be absolute URIs.

Comment: id '/items' is used to define it as an Array. We can rule this our since its parent id's are different.

Comment: You misunderstand my what I'm telling you.  `id`s don't nest the way the way you are expecting them to.  They need to be unique with no consideration of where they are defined.  You could use "/Coupon/items" and "/Rewards/items" instead and it will be what you expect, but you can't use "/items" twice regardless of the parent `id`s.  That's not a concept that exists in JSON Schema.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (anyone else landing here to find similar issue),
we had a schema file in this format:

```
{
  "keyA": {
    "type": "string",
    "example": "0319739002",
    "id": "/keyA",
    "minLength": 1,
    "maxLength": 100
  },
  "keyB": {
    "keyA": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "0186013001",
      "id": "/keyA",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 100
    }
  }
}
```

where keyA was a part of keyB, but the id was repeated. Removing (/renaming) the 'id' field worked for us.